How to remove pod's current version?
I use Mac book( os version: Sonoma 14.4.1, Apple M2)
The current cocoa pod version on my laptop is 1.14.3 (run "pod --version")
But When I "run sudo gem uninstall cocoapods", the terminal showed as follows:
You have requested to uninstall the gem:
cocoapods-1.15.2
It looks like 1.15.2 is my current version.
If I run the command "sudo gem list cocoapods", I got the following answer:
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
cocoapods (1.15.2)
cocoapods-azure-universal-packages (0.1.1)
cocoapods-core (1.15.2)
cocoapods-deintegrate (1.0.5)
cocoapods-downloader (2.1)
cocoapods-plugins (1.0.0)
cocoapods-search (1.0.1)
cocoapods-trunk (1.6.0)
cocoapods-try (1.2.0)
I tried to uninstall the current pod version by running "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods", then I found I deleted the version 1.15.2.
If I run "pod --version", it still showed: 1.14.3
But If I run "sudo gem uninstall cocoapods" again, it showed:
Gem 'cocoapods' is not installed
So I am confused about where the pod 1.14.3 installed. I really want to delete the version 1.14.3, because it caused some problems with our current project.
Any suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Did you install CocoaPods with HomeBrew, explaining why the gem version is different?

Yes, I just found that I installed the pods with HomeBrew. I will delete this pods using brew uninstall command. Thanks for reminding me.
